# How many digits can be removed from a division puzzle?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, missing-digits

Similarly to [How many digits can be removed from a multiplication puzzle and still give only one answer?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/464/how-many-digits-can-be-removed-from-a-multiplication-puzzle-and-still-give-only) I am curious about division puzzles.

I know this puzzle:

[image].

It has only 2 out of 42 digits $\approx$ 4.8% digits shown.

Is there a puzzle with less percent of digits shown?

Comment: I have seen a similar puzzle without the last zero.  That reduces the count yet farther.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for least percentage, without concerning with the Difficulty of the puzzle.

In that case, the percentage can be made **arbitrarily small**.
Here is an example with **31** digits removed:

```
999)*********(*******
    ***
       ***
       ***
          ***
          ***
            0
```

Here the format AAA)BBB(CCC means AAA is dividing BBB to get the answer as CCC.

We can extend the same arbitrarily, eg here is the next possibility with **43** digits removed:

```
999)************(**********
    ***
       ***
       ***
          ***
          ***
             ***
             ***
               0
```

We now list the third example with **55** digits removed:

```
999)***************(*************
    ***
       ***
       ***
          ***
          ***
             ***
             ***
                ***
                ***
                  0
```

We now list a fourth example with **67** digits removed:

```
999)******************(****************
    ***
       ***
       ***
          ***
          ***
             ***
             ***
                ***
                ***
                   ***
                   ***
                     0
```

Enough Examples, let us generalise this, such that 999 Divides a (3N)-Digit number with a (3N-2)-Digit number as the answer.

Calculating the percentage:

> 999)************[3N '*' characters](**********[3N-2 '*' characters]

This will contain totally (3N)+(3N-2)+(3N)+(3N-3) = 12N-5 '*' characters, when counting all the rows.

With 4 known digits [9,9,9,0] , total number of digits = 12N-1.

Percentage of known digits = 100*(4)/(12N-1).

We can take N = 100, for example, to get **0.3%**.

We can take N = 1000 to get **0.03%**.

**EDIT:**

Solutions to those puzzles will be like this:
The result Digits will be 1001001...001 (1 followed by 001 (N-1) times).
All remaining unknown Digits will be 9s.

```
999)999999999(1001001
    999
       999
       999
          999
          999
            0
```

```
999)999999999999(1001001001
    999
       999
       999
          999
          999
             999
             999
               0
```

Comment: What do ")" and "(" mean?

Comment: That is one way to write the Divisions: "999)999999(1001" means 999 is Dividing 999999, and the answer is 1001.

Comment: In your representation, you would have written 999999 on the left, 999 on the right, and 1001 below that.

Comment: Looks like someone's going for a Necromancer badge ;-)

Comment: I see. Could you write few words about solution?

Comment: (A) I have added few pointers about the solutions. (B) I was not aware of the Necromancer badge [newbie here !!], but I did get the Revival badge !!

Answer (score 5):

Remarkably, there are long division problems (WITH NO DIGITS GIVEN!) that have a unique solution.

The following problem was given in the Eureka journal (April 1978/University of Cambridge).  This problem can be solved by hand without computers.

[image: Long division puzzle with all digits missing]

Unique solution:

> $\Large\frac{631938}{625}$

Comment: Great puzzle but decimal point is a bit of a game changer though

Answer (score 3):

In *More Mathematical Puzzles and Diversions*, ch. 14, Nine More Problems, problem 5, Martin Gardner gives the problem of reconstructing the following long division:

```
       xx8xx
xxx)xxxxxxxx
     xxx
     ---
      xxxx
       xxx
      ----
        xxxx
        xxxx
        ----
```

Gardner credits the problem to P. L. Chessin of the Westinghouse Electric Corporation, and cites the April 1954 issue of *American Mathematical Monthly*. The answer is

> 10020316/124=80809